# Show dependency graph in Idea for modules only

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, intellij-idea-2016

Is it possible to create a maven dependency graph with Idea, that contains module dependencies only?
With module dependencies I mean all sub or parent modules defined in pom.xml files within the `<modules>` or `<parent>` tags. The default dependency graph shows all dependencies which is a bit to much information.

I already found out how to generate the module dependency tree by clicking `Analyze -> Analyze Module Dependencies...`
But this just shows the tree and not a graph.